# MS-Access group by column having count(*) > 1 weird behavior?

Tags: ms-access

I am playing around with ms-access (MS-Office Professional Plus 2013) trying to figure out if I have duplicate rows before I merge one table into another table.  I want to collect the rows that are duplicates and give an error with the duplicates before the merge happens.  I have two scenarios to cover.  The first scenario is duplicates on a single column.  The second scenario is duplicates on two columns.  Any help on the first scenario would be appreciated.

Scenario 1:
The two tables have the exact same column structure so to keep it simple I will use the following table structure.  ( I simply added two tables inside access and run the query to figure out the correct syntax.)

```
Duplicates based upon one column:
    Table1    Table2
    ID        ID       
    1         1
    2         3
```

Running the query:
Select ID from Table1
Union ALL
Select ID from Table2
group by ID having count(*) > 1

The result set is always the records from the first select statement. In other words it always returns Id=1 and Id=2.  If you change Table1 to Table2 the result set is always from table2.  If I change "Union all" to union same results.  I tried changing the ID column names as well as change the type to be number instead of auto.  Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Scenario 2: I know what the value should be in the second column so it is hard-coded.  I added this here to show access appears to work as expected in this scenario but not in scenario 1.

```
Duplicates based upon two columns:  
    Table1             Table2
    ID   Field1        ID   Field1
    1    abc           1    abc
    2    bcd           3    abc
```

Running the query below works as expected. The row with ID=1 is only returned.
select  ID, Field1 from Table1 where Field1 = 'abc'
union all
select  ID, Field1 from Table2  where Field1 = 'abc'
group by ID, Field1 having count(*) > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` is only being applied to the second table. You need to do the `UNION ALL` first, and then the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` on a `SELECT` from the combined results.

Not Access specific, but something like this works:

```
SELECT id FROM
(
  SELECT id FROM a
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT id FROM b
) AS c
GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

My preferred way to do things like that is to use the build in Query Wizard:

**Query Wizard, Find Duplicates Query Wizard**

Let Access create the SQL statement for you and then you can modify it and/or move it into code.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. It states your preference, not how to solve the SQL problem as the question asks.

Comment: @KenWhite: I am sure if I would have written a comment others would write if should be an answer so they can vote it up or down. Now people can vote it up or down...    My answer is solution how to get the correct SQL syntax in above case and other cases. That should make this answer useful for many situations. Vote it up or down...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, since the _find duplicates_ wizard only takes a single table, and the whole problem is introduced because the OP is searching for duplicates on multiple tables.

Comment: OK. I gave you the chance to edit or remove it. You made it. :-)

Comment: I looked at the wizard just to see what was available.  The wizard lets you find duplicates on a single table.  If you want to do duplicates against more than one table you have to learn how to use the GUI to do what you want or write the query.